# I'm confused by Linq XML query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Here is my XML sample. I want to select SystemSetting's value if `ID = 123`. But I can't figure out how. How can I select `SystemSetting` value if id's value equal to 123 ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Private>
  <System>
    <ID>123</ID>
    <NAME>Test</NAME>
    <SystemSetting>128</SystemSetting>
    <SystemSettingCS>127</SystemSettingCS>
  </System> 
  <System>
    <ID>124</ID>
    <NAME>Test2</NAME>
    <SystemSetting>128</SystemSetting>
    <SystemSettingCS>127</SystemSettingCS>
  </System>
  <System>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <NAME>Test</NAME>   
    <SystemSetting>5</SystemSetting>
    <SystemSettingCS>250</SystemSettingCS>
  </System>
</Private>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath+  @"\Settings.xml");
    var q = from Ana in doc.Descendants("Private")                   
            from sistem in Ana.Elements("System")                   
            where (int)sistem.Element("ID") == 123
            from assetText in Sistem.Elements("System")
            select assetText.Element("SystemSetting");

    MessageBox.Show(q.ToString());
```

thnx for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than you need to. I think you just need:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("Private") // Or just doc.Root
               .Elements("System")
               .Where(x => (int) x.Element("ID") == 123)
               .Select(x => x.Element("SystemSetting"))
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will select the *first* matching element, admittedly. The type of `query` is then `XElement`; if you take off the `FirstOrDefault()` part, it will return an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, for all matching elements.

If you want just the value instead of the element, you can change the `Select` to:

```
.Select(x => (string) x.Element("SystemSetting"))
```

or

```
.Select(x => x.Element("SystemSetting").Value)
```

(The first will return `null` if there's no `SystemSetting` element; the second will throw an exception.)

Comment: Wouldn't you need a `.Value` after the `x.Element(..)`'s?

Comment: @CodingGorilla: To get the string value, yes. The OP's original code only fetches the XElement, so that's what I did too. Will edit to offer other options though.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath (*System.Xml.XPath*) can really help here

```
var system = doc.XPathSelectElement("//System[ID[text()='123']]");
var val = system.Element("SystemSetting").Value;
```

or with a single line

```
var s = (string)doc.XPathSelectElement("//System[ID[text()='123']]/SystemSetting");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var q = from s in doc.Descendants("System")  
         where (int)s.Element("ID") == 123        
         select (int)s.Element("SystemSetting");
```

And show result (`q` will have `IEnumerable<int>` type):

```
if (q.Any())
    MessageBox.Show("SystemSettings = " + q.First());
else
    MessageBox.Show("System not found");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your almost there

```
var xmlFile = XElement.Load(@"c:\\test.xml");

var query =
  from e in xmlFile.Elements()
  where e.Element("ID").Value == "123"
  select e.Element("SystemSetting").Value;
```

Comment: Note that that won't restrict to `System` elements. It's fine if there aren't any other elements, as per the sample, but I'd personally restrict it.

Answer (score 0):

Was a Linq question, but there is an alternate XPath approach, but the class defined below could work in either scenario.

Define a class to read from the parent System element:

```
public class XSystem
{
   public XSystem(XElement xSystem) { self = xSystem; }
   XElement self;

   public int Id { get { return (int)self.Element("ID"); } }
   public string Name { get { return self.Element("NAME").Value; } }
   public int SystemSetting { get { return (int)self.Element("SystemSetting"); } }
   public int SystemSettingCS { get { return (int)self.Element("SystemSettingCS"); } }
}
```

Then find your **System** element that has a child **ID** element of **123**.

```
int id = 123;
string xpath = string.Format("//System[ID={0}", id);
XElement x = doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
```

Then plug it into the class:

```
XSystem system = new XSystem(x);
```

Then read the value you want:

```
int systemSetting = system.SystemSetting;
```

XPath is defined with `using System.Xml.XPath;`